# How to access a list-within-a-list inside a hash env in R, like for a Python dict

Tags: r, dictionary, hash, environment, nested-lists

I am trying to use the `hash` package in R to replicate dictionary behavior in python. I have created it like this,

```
library(hash)
titles = hash(NAME = list("exact"=list('NAME','Age'), "partial"=list()),
              Dt   = list("exact"=list('Dt'), "partial"=list()),
              CC   = list("exact"=list(), "partial"=list()))
```

I can access the keys in the hash using `keys(titles)` , values using `values(titles)`, and access values for a particular key using `values(titles['Name'])`.

But how can I access the elements of the inner list? e.g. `list('NAME','Age')` ?
I need to access the elements based on its names, in this case - "exact" or else I need to know which element of the outer list this element belong to, whether its "exact" or "partial".

Comment: `titles$NAME$exact ; titles$Dt$exact ; titles$CC$exact` If you _really_ need to bring gosh-awful Python syntax into R, `titles[["NAME"]][["exact"]]`. Note that you can do the same thing you seem to be trying to do with just `list`s: `titles <- list(NAME=list(exact=list('NAME', 'Age'), partial=list()), Dt=list(exact=list('Dt'), partial=list()))`

Comment: Thank you. That works. :)  By the way, I am not very sure how to use the key/value pair concepts in list, thats why I prefer to use hash which is replicating the dictionary concept in python.

Comment: @jeevag you're not very clear, how specifically is this different to accessing a Python dict? What breaks? Give specific code example.

Comment: @hrbrmstr `titles[["NAME"]][["exact"]]` is in fact the recommended proper R syntax (esp. when the key is variable), it's not "bringing gosh-awful Python syntax" ;-)

Comment: Actually `$` is even more flexible. Both `[[` and `$` select a single element of a list. The main difference is that `$` does not allow computed indices, whereas `[[` does. `x$name` is equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`. If you like being verbose, why not `getElement(x, name) `?

Comment: @hrbmstr: the R doc itself prefers `[["mykey"]]` to `$mykey` for referencing named lists/hashes. Also, obviously `$` only works when the key name is fixed and known in advance - which is really not a great way of writing extensible code. Why make simple things complicated...?

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
titles[["NAME"]][["exact"]]
```

as hrbmstr wrote. There's nothing special about this whatsoever.

In your nested-list, "exact" and "partial" are simply two string keys. Again, there's no special magic significance to their names.

Also, this is in fact the recommended proper R syntax (esp. when the key is variable), it's not "bringing gosh-awful Python syntax".